# Laravel, Undefined Variable when trying to pass array from controller to views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i'm pretty new to Laravel and still trying to figure all of this out. So basically I have an array with a list of movies that I want to pass onto my index.blade.php file. Then show that list in my index file. This is what I have currently.

Route:

```
Route::get('catalog', 'App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');
```

Controller:

```
class CatalogController extends Controller
{
    private $arrayPeliculas = array(...);

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('catalog.index', $this->arrayPeliculas);
    }
}
```

Index:

```
<body>
    @section('content')
    <div class="row">

        @foreach( $arrayPeliculas as $key => $pelicula )
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 text-center">

            <a href="{{ url('/catalog/show/' . $key ) }}">
                <img src="{{$pelicula['poster']}}" style="height:200px"/>
                <h4 style="min-height:45px;margin:5px 0 10px 0">
                    {{$pelicula['title']}}
                </h4>
            </a>

        </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>
    @endsection
</body>
```

I tried doing it a different way that did sort of work

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $arrayPeliculas = array(...);
        return view('catalog.index')->with('arrayPeliculas', $arrayPeliculas);
    }
```

But that doesn't really work for me since I have a few other functions that use this array and when the array is modified it would only be within that specific function.
I've looked for similar questions but I don't see what i'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Instead of `->with('arrayPeliculas', $arrayPeliculas);` try `->with('arrayPeliculas' => $arrayPeliculas);`

Comment: That seems to be giving me  syntax error: unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

Comment: My bad, I forgot to wrap it into an array `(['arrayPeliculas' => $arrayPeliculas])`

Comment: Ok, it didn't give me an error but it is still saying Undefined Variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this

```php
 return view(
           'catalog.index',
           ['arrayPeliculas' => $this->arrayPeliculas]
);
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks a lot! I'm still not very familiar with the syntax and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the variable with compact because you defined it earlier
You should use this return view('catalog.index',compact('arrayPeliculas'));

Answer (score 0):

your code should  be like bellow

```php
return view('catalog.index',compact('arrayPeliculas'));
```